# Is there a better way to make complex cloth, than sculpting it?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I want to make this exact white blanket.

[image]

How would you go about creating such a fluffy, extremly wrinkled blanket.

I went through some tutorials, but they only deal with very simple blankets.

I would like to get it to like 80% before starting to make the details with sculpting. The smaller blankets on top should fall into place much easier, once the big white one is done and can function as a collision object.

I also want to constrain myself to blender and dont want to do it in marvelous or etc.

Edit:

Rigg Riggs answer works perfectly as startingpoint.

[image]

You can rotate the imageplane used for the displacement-texture to control the direction of the patter without messing it up . Thats how i got it to go diagonally.
I also used two diffuse shaders (b/w) in a mix, controlled by the noise texture, instead of his node setup. Seems to work better. At least for me.
Had to play around with the settings a bit before getting a texture to my liking.
I added a decimate modifier set to un-subdivide and a triangulate modifier  once i applied the displacement, to reduce the face-count.

If you have a different approach please feel free to share it. Im trying to learn :)

Comment: you could also change the `Rotation >> Z` property on the Mapping node to get your rotation on the texture image itself.

Comment: doesnt work if you scaled it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render out a texture on plane similar to the following & save the image:
[image]

Add a plane to the 3D view > subdivide it like crazy (<kbd>W</kbd> >> <kbd>S</kbd>)

Add a Displacement Modifier

Create a new texture from here.

Go into the textures tab on the properties panel and set the texture to your rendered out image location on disk.

Come back to the modifiers tab and play with your settings, start with mine here and adjust to your liking.

finally add a subsurf modifier

Last apply the subsurf modifier, then the displacement modifier.

Then go into sculpt mode and have your way with it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One important mention, set your render engine to cycles before trying to create the texture in this answer.

Comment: Interesting Solution to this problem. Will try to remember it for the future.

Comment: Might also note that going too crazy with subdivides on some machines may cause performance issues with attempting to sculpt afterward.

Comment: I`ll try this. It looks really promising. And much faster than doing it with cloth. Thank you :). Will update my question with results