# Modelling a modern dome tent

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, sculpting, cloth-simulation

I am trying to model a dome tent with four sides for an outdoor night scene but I cannot figure out the modelling approach. I have seen [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41982/how-to-model-a-dome-tent) question and it helps to make the basic shape, but I want to make it as real as possible with big wrinkles and stuff. I have tried sculpting and cloth sim with pinning and stuff but it doesn't look good.
So if you can tell how would approach it, it would be really helpful.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: have you checked this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102020/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-complex-cloth-than-sculpting-it?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. This would help but still I would not be able to create the stretching effect along the corners and where the pipe is attaches to the cloth.

Comment: You could try inflating a square pyramid, or something like it, using Rich Colburn's [Modeling Cloth](https://youtu.be/yHGz7nEI23E?t=1000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should get something pretty good with sculpting, you just need to observe how the fabric behaves. Here's a quick try, I've given the object a *Multiresolution* modifier, when you're fine you can bake the normals, delete the *Multiresolution* modifier and use the normal map on the original low-res version.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks pretty good. Are you using any specific brushes of the default ones? Also, any idea how to create the stretches where the tent is clipped to the frame?

Comment: I've added the wireframe, it's just the basic shape with a bevel on each corner. For the brushes: I'm very bad at sculpting so I just used the basic SculptDraw brush, sometimes brought some corrections with shift or ctrl, I guess with some experience you can do much better, but again the key thing is to see how the fabric behaves. Now maybe it's feasible with cloth physic simulation but I don't know enough about cloth...

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually waiting if someone answers using cloth sim with better results or I'll accept this :)

Answer (score 1):

Your base is great already... Maybe you should try some displacement modifier on chosen vertex groups ? Those stretches you made should be bigger, too (see your reference image, they seem to go all the way). I would try creases with a very light brush in sculpt mode, which I guess you tried already, but wider strokes with less intensity.